# Setting a JavaScript variable value from Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I specifically want to call Android, when in offline mode, for a large chunk of data to be returned to JavaScript.

This is a doable solution for small amounts of data:

```
(Android)
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function () { " +
                           "setVariable("+valueToSetInHtmlPage+");" +
                           "})()");

(HTML callback function)
function setVariable(AndroidInput)
{
alert(AndroidInput);
}
```

This approach is limited by the allowed URL size which might very between browsers.
But never the less a blocking limit when dealing with large data (+10KB)

Is there any other ways to pass values from Android to JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look into WebView's [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) function. This'll let you "hand over" a Java object into JS.

```
public void addJavascriptInterface (Object obj, String interfaceName)
```

> Since: API Level 1 Use this function to bind an object to JavaScript
>   so that the methods can be accessed from JavaScript.

Comment: I believe you are right :)
This is how i was making the link between JS and Android.
But i was returning the value via. WebView.loadURL (WRONG!!)

Thanks